# Update a table with values from a related table

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements, transfer

I have two tables, `Users` and `Company`.

I want to transfer values from a `Active` column in the `Users` table to the `Active` column in the `Company` table, where the `CompanyID` in matches `ID`.

This is an example table. It has many thousands of rows, and there is 1 on 1 relationship between `Company` and `Users`:

```
Users:
CompanyID    Active
458          1
685          1
58           0

Company:
ID           Active
5            Null
3            Null
58           Null
685          Null
```

The final `Company` table should look something like this where the `Null` has been replaced with the value from the `Users` table.

```
Company:
ID           Active
5            Null
3            Null
58           0
685          1
```

Comment: Are both MySQL and MS SQL Server used here? (Don't tag products not involved...)

Comment: Sorry just SQL server

Comment: What have you tried? What about when there is more than 1 User for a Company?

Comment: basic join here. very very basic :)

Comment: Basic Merge Join too

Comment: there are companies without user. did they never have a user or did some1 delete that user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply perform an `UPDATE` that uses a `JOIN` between the two tables like so:

```
UPDATE c
SET Active = u.Active
FROM Company c
INNER JOIN Users u ON u.CompanyId = c.ID
```

**Full working sample code:**

```
CREATE TABLE #Users
    (
      CompanyId INT ,
      Active BIT
    )

INSERT  INTO #Users
        ( CompanyId, Active )
VALUES  ( 458, 1 ),
        ( 685, 1 ),
        ( 58, 0 )

CREATE TABLE #Company
    (
      ID INT ,
      Active BIT
    )

INSERT  INTO #Company
        ( ID, Active )
VALUES  ( 5, NULL ),
         ( 3, NULL ),
         ( 58, NULL ),
         ( 685, NULL )

UPDATE c
SET Active = u.Active
FROM #Company c
INNER JOIN #Users u ON u.CompanyId = c.ID

SELECT * FROM #Company

DROP TABLE #Users
DROP TABLE #Company
```

You'll notice that the `UPDATE` statement in the sample code uses aliases `c` and `u` to reference the two tables.

**Caveat:**

As stated in the comments, this assumes that you only ever have a 1 to 1 relationship between `Company` and `Users`. If there is more than one user assigned to the same company, you will need to filter the `Users` to pick the one you want to use, otherwise you may get unexpected results.

Comment: in case there are more than 1 user for a company, you will not have any control of which active code is being the end result

Comment: @t-clausen.dk OP updated question to state there is a 1-1 relationship

Comment: @t-clausen.dk i was working on a separate query to cover that case but binned it after the update to the question

Answer (score 2):

That should do the trick for you.

```
DECLARE @Users TABLE (CompanyID INT, Active BIT);
DECLARE @Companies TABLE (CompanyID INT, Active BIT);

INSERT INTO @Users (CompanyID, Active)
VALUES (458, 1), (685, 1), (58, 0)

INSERT INTO @Companies (CompanyID)
VALUES (5),(3),(58),(685)


SELECT C.CompanyID, U.Active
FROM @Companies AS C
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP (1) U.Active
    FROM @Users AS U
    WHERE U.CompanyID = C.CompanyID
    ORDER BY U.Active DESC
    ) AS U(Active)
```

**Result:**

```
CompanyID   Active
------------------
5           NULL
3           NULL
58          0
685         1
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have more users for each company, I would assume that 1 active user would result in an active company.

```
UPDATE
  Company
SET Active = (SELECT top 1 Active
              FROM Users 
              WHERE CompanyId = Company.id
              ORDER BY Active DESC)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Company
SET Company.Active = u.Active from Users u
where Company.ID = u.CompanyID
```

Comment: for future reference, it's usually a good idea to add some sort of explanation to answers, otherwise it will automatically be submitted for  review for being code only.